# One outcome variable, many nested predictors -which model to use?

Tags: r, mixed-model

Say I have a dataset such as the one below. We have several subjects (`id`). For each subject we have one outcome of interest (`out`). We want to see if we are able to predict this outcome based on the values of one predictor (`var`). Per individual, we have several values of `var`, and they are blocked into different time periods `time`.

```
   id  out time var
1   A 1.56    1  58
2   A 1.56    1  55
3   A 1.56    1  59
4   A 1.56    2  60 
5   A 1.56    2  61
6   A 1.56    2  64
7   A 1.56    3  64
8   A 1.56    3  67
9   A 1.56    3  69
10  B 1.66    1  51
11  B 1.66    1  53
12  B 1.66    1  49
13  B 1.66    2  52
14  B 1.66    2  60
15  B 1.66    2  60
16  B 1.66    3  59
17  B 1.66    3  62
18  B 1.66    3  65
19  C 1.11    1  49
20  C 1.11    1  54
21  C 1.11    1  43
22  C 1.11    2  49
23  C 1.11    2  41
24  C 1.11    2  41
25  C 1.11    3  50
26  C 1.11    3  40
27  C 1.11    3  55
```

Some example R code:

```
data.frame(
  id = rep(LETTERS[1:3],each=9),
  out = rep(c(1.56, 1.66, 1.11), each=9),
  time = rep(rep(1:3,each=3),3),
  var = c(58, 55, 59, 60, 61, 64, 64, 67, 69,
          51, 53, 49, 52, 60, 60, 59, 62, 65,
          49, 54, 43, 49, 41, 41, 50, 40, 55)
)
```

Is the most appropriate approach here to start with a mixed-effect model such as:

`mod <- lmer(out ~ var + time + (1|id), data=df)`

This doesn't seem right to me at first glance. What would be the most appropriate way of modeling the outcome variable, given we only have one value measured per individual ?

Comment: Abstractly, this problem potentially has many good solutions.  To narrow them down, please tell us what these data mean or at least describe your theories about how the outcome is related to the collection of predictors for each individual.

Comment: The outcome variable is a biological measure of cortisol (stress hormone).  The predictor variable is a measure of self-reported stress by respondents. They report that three times a week for 3 weeks prior to the biological measure.

Comment: Does that mean "time" is really the reporting time rounded up to the nearest whole week?  Would it be fair to view each sequence of nine values of `var` as occurring in the order presented, so that in effect you have nine explanatory variables?

Comment: yes, it would be like getting a value for stress on Mon/Wed/Fri of three successive weeks.